# JSON objects wont transfer into js array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I get undefined when i try to console.log it

```
var farr = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "https://whispering-cliffs-33347.herokuapp.com/employees",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/jsonp"
}).done(function(employees) {
    for(let i in employees){
        farr.push(employees[i]);
    }
})
console.log(farr[8]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First console `employees`. Know whether it is array or object. If it is array, you may need to parse the JSON. And use console in `.done` function.

Comment: Move the `console.log` call into your `.done()` callback.  Remember that `$.ajax` is asynchronous and any return values or variables you're setting in the callback will be undefined outside of the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: just use async:false

Comment: No, do not use `async:false`.  It's deprecated, it's lazy and it's poor programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(farr[8]);` will be executed even before the response is available.So in first `done` push all the elements in the local array & once that is done in the next `done` log the value

```
var farr = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://whispering-cliffs-33347.herokuapp.com/employees",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/jsonp"
    }).done(function(employees) {
        employees.forEach(function(item){
            farr.push(item)
        })
    }).done(function(elem){
        console.log(farr[8]);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate the object with standard for loop. To be able to do that, you should first get object keys in an array and iterate over that.

```
const keys = Object.keys(employees);
keys.forEach((i) => {
     farr.push(employees[i]);
 }
 console.log(farr[8]);. // You should put this in the call back itself
```

Or you can directly iterate over the object using lodash's forEach.